# Migrating old MySQL code to new version of MySQL. I can't find error here involving ENGINE=MyISAM

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Here is my error information :

```
CREATE TABLE `mb_topics` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `locked` char(1) NOT NULL default 'N',
  `boardid` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `postedon` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `lastpost` bigint(20) NOT NULL default '1',
  `message2` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `under` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
  `under2` int(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `postbyid` int(8) NOT NULL default '0',
  `postedat` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near **'(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISA' at line 20**
```

I googled parts of this code and I didn't find any similar issues. There was one about changing TYPE=MyISAM to ENGINE=MyISAM but I already read that one. 
Can someone help point out the error here?

Thanks, and happy new years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 `postedat` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
```

to

```
 `postedat` timestamp NOT NULL,
```